# ADOMD.NET 9.0 Redistributable?

Tags: sql-server-2008, olap, redistributable, adomd.net

Got a problem with ADOMD.NET 8.0, SQL2008 and our app. It isn't giving us the right metadata.

I can't find anywhere to download the ADOMD.NET 9.0 redistributable. Only way I can get it is by installing 2008 and grabbing the DLL.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL 2008 Feature Pack which includes ADOMD.NET is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=228de03f-3b5a-428a-923f-58a033d316e1&displaylang=en&tm), which has links to the individual MSIs.

Comment: Thankyou! You don't know how long I've been messing around trying to fix this!

Answer (score 1):

Hum, that is for v10 (2008) not v9 (2005)
Microsoft ADOMD.NET

> ADOMD.NET is a Microsoft .NET Framework object model that enables software developers to create client-side applications that browse metadata and query data stored in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services. ADOMD.NET is a Microsoft ADO.NET provider with enhancements for online analytical processing (OLAP) and data mining.
>
> Note:The English ADOMD.NET setup package installs support for all SQL Server 2008 languages.
>
> Audience(s): Customer, Partner, Developer
>
> ```
>     X86 Package(SQLSERVER2008_ASADOMD10.msi) - 4312 KB
>     X64 Package (SQLSERVER2008_ASADOMD10.msi) - 9263 KB
>     IA64 Package(SQLSERVER2008_ASADOMD10.msi) - 6776 KB
> ```

See the link
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15748
for 2005 v9 version

Answer (score 1):

You can also install it from [NuGet](http://Install-Package%20Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient).

Run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient
```

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Instead, tailor each of your answers to the specific question. If you have the necessary reputation points, you can [flag](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) or [vote-to-close](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) questions as duplicates, where appropriate.